# Rails erb style background-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

It's a simple question, but I just can't get the right result

The original html is

```
 <section class="pageTitle" style="background-image:url(img/pages/page-title-bg8.jpg);">
```

But now I need to rewrite it into the version of `erb`

I wrote the following code, but it fails.

```
<section class="pageTitle" style="background-image: url(<%= image_url 'img/pages/page-title-bg8.jpg' %>);">
```

### Update

It becomes

```
<section class="pageTitle" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/images/img/pages/page-title-bg8.jpg);">
```

Comment: how does it show up in the html?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `image_url` with `asset_path`.

If that doesn't work, create a class and to the css file add:

`.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }`

Comment: I think `class` will work, because I use `class` all the time. But I felt confused about this way. I've updated my question.

Comment: that's haml though